# How to use a dictionary as tick value labels with Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I searched on the site and found some questions related to my problem but it did not work for me and I'm not sure I know why.

I have a dataframe with three columns :

```
Section,Score,Status2
A,90,2
A,92,1
B,81,2
A,85,1
B,89,1
B,78,1
A,82,2
B,84,1
A,88,2
B,91,1
```

I want to make a catplot representing the Score (`y`) by the Status2 (`x`), with an HUE (Section).

```py
# -- Settings
hue_order = ["B", "A"]
palette = ["g", "b"]

# -- Graph
catscp_py = sns.catplot(
    data=df,
    kind="strip",
    x="Status2",
    y="Score",
    hue="Section",
    hue_order=hue_order,
    palette=palette,
)

# -- Customization
plt.xlabel(xlabel="Status", fontsize=7)
plt.ylabel(ylabel="Score", fontsize=7)
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(np.arange(70, 100, 5))
```

[image: Here's the output.]

I do not want to get the `xtickvalues` as is `(1, 2)`. This is an integer column, it has to be displayed in this numerical order (so I can not derive a new character column I guess). I just want to put a dictionary on the tick to display something else.

I created two dictionaries, just for testing:

```py
dic_status = {1:'Status E1', 2:'Status D1'}
    
dic_status2 = {'Status E1': 1, 'Status D1': 2}
```

So I tried to add this code part on my previous code:

```py
plt.xticks(
    np.arange(1, 2, 1),
    df['Status2'].map(dic_status)
)
```

Whatever the dictionary I'm using, I get this message:

> ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (1), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (10).

I think I understand the issue: the dataframe as 10 records, so I guess the code tries to find ten modalities in the dictionary. But I have only two (that's normal according to me). I tried this code on a dataframe with only two records (Status2 = 1 and Status2 = 2, with the number of observation associated in another column), this is working.

I tried this but this is not how I want to do it:

```
plt.xticks(
    [0, 1], 
    ["Status E1", "Status D1"]
)
```

[image: Here's the output.]

In this example, the low amount of modalities of Score2 makes it easy. Still in the future I'll have to deal with a lot of integer values, so I would prefer to not use this way.

That's why I would like to use dictionaries instead. Could you give me some advices? I found also some answers for Matplotlib (ax.) but still not working with this dataframe.

Thank you very much !

Comment: Also note that `np.arange(1, 2, 1)` is just the array `[1]`.  See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a different `x` column by mapping your dictionary over the `Status2` column and using that in `sns.catplot`:

```py
dic_status = {1: "Status E1", 2: "Status D1"}
df["Status2_mapped"] = df["Status2"].map(dic_status)
```

Then we can plot using `sns.catplot`, which returns a [`sns.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) that we can manipulate directly:

```py
# -- Settings
hue_order = ["B", "A"]
palette = ["g", "b"]

# -- Graph
grid = sns.catplot(
    data=df,
    kind="strip",
    x="Status2_mapped",
    y="Score",
    hue="Section",
    hue_order=hue_order,
    palette=palette,
    # Set the order of the groups using the dict
    order=dic_status.values(),
)

# -- Customization
grid.set_axis_labels("Status", "Score", fontsize=7)
grid.set_xticklabels(fontsize=15)
grid.set(yticks=np.arange(70, 100, 5))
```

Which outputs:

[image: sns catplot with changed xlabels]

Comment: Hello Alex and thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately I tried this solution before posting and as you can see the tick order is now reversed and sorted alphabetically. As I mentionned in my question, I need to keep sur order of the integer column (Status2). So I should get "Status E1" (=1) and then "Status D1" (=2). I made this dictionary on purpose, just to control that the values appear in the right order. That's why I think I do need to keep the integer column as "x". But I don't know how to put a dictionnary onto it, just for the final display.

Comment: Alex, thanks so much, it's working now. I did not know I could use the order parameter like this.